# Problem passing value as well as accessing Child Component

Tags: angular

I have a form which has for elements , Company, Contact, date as well as a customer component which is date picker. I can pick enter all the values in the form and when i hit submit i get all of them except the component which is a custom one.
I am using reactive forms and i am assigning the form control like this.

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form" (submit)="create(form.value)">
<br><br>
<igx-input-group>
    <input igxInput name="companyName" 
            type="text"
            formControlName="company"
            />
    <label igxLabel for="companyName">Company Name</label>
</igx-input-group>
<igx-input-group>
    <input igxInput name="contact" 
            type="text"
            formControlName="contact"
            />
    <label igxLabel for="companyName">Contact Name</label>
</igx-input-group>
<div>   
        <label for="date-picker">Basic Control</label>
        <igx-date-picker 
            id="date-picker" 
            #editable mode="dropdown" 
            format="shortDate" mask="dd-MM-y"
            formControlName="date">
        </igx-date-picker>   
        <label>Date: {{ editable.value | date:'fullDate' }}</label>
    </div>

    <app-igx-date-picker
    formControlName="datepicker"
    todayLabel="Today"
    closeLabel="we are done"
    showMonth="2"
    >
    </app-igx-date-picker>
<br>
<br>
<button igxButton="raised" (click)="writeStuff()" igxRipple="white">Submit Form</button>
<button igxButton="raised"  (click)="getDateCompvalue()" igxButtonColor="yellow" igxButtonBackground="#000" igxRipple="yellow" >Get Value</button>

</form>
```

Another issue i am facing is the **"ERROR Error: v is not a function"**

i searched my sample code and cant find either a v or v()

To make it simpler i enclosed the sample on [Stackblitz Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-s61p6b-djs7j5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Figx-date-picker%2Figx-date-picker.component.ts)

Comment: https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73 I think this tutorial will help you too much

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a formGroup in a child component, the way you have to do it is:

1. Pass the formGroup in using `@Input()`
2. Instead of creating a new form Group, use `this.form.AddControl('selected', this.selected);`

It will work like a charm after :)

Comment: can you please provide a some sample of how to.. i tried several diffrent ones but still get errror I creted a @input called formGroup of type FormGroup but how do initialize it with the form based from the input ?

Comment: So on your `app.component.html`


```
    <app-igx-date-picker
   ** [form]="form"**
    todayLabel="Today"
    closeLabel="we are done"
    showMonth="2"
    >
    </app-igx-date-picker>
```

and on your `igx-date-picker.component.ts`, add

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
```

and on your `ngOnInit()`:
```
ngOnInit() {
      this.selected = new FormControl(this.value, [], );
      this.form.addControl('selected', this.selected)
  }
```

Comment: In short, you don't do `this.form = new FormGroup()` at all in the child component. You need to use the form group passed in as an Input by the parent